# Do you know this S curve's name?

Tags: predictive-modeling, marketing, simulation

I'm making a ad-sales predictor and try to make it fit by using the S curve's below.

$ ()= \frac{}{1+} (1−^{−}) $

- $f(x)$ is an ad-sales
- $x$ is an advertise cost
- both $a$ and $b$ are fitting parameters.

It looks like logistic function curve. I actually don't know a name of it though I have to use it for our client order. Do you know a name of the function or any text referring it?

Comment: I would guess that $a, b, x$ are all $\ge 0$?

Answer (score 5):

From a quick search, the function you provided doesn't seem to have a particular name.

Are you sure the function belongs to Sigmoidal curves? The [function](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dzrub58we2) does not remind too much of an S-shape.